# Angular and contenteditable

Tags: angular, events, contenteditable

I've searched the web but can't find a way to work with `contenteditable` events on Angular 6/7. Angular seems to have a messy solution with it but said feature doesn't seem to be carried over to recent versions.

A use case would be is on a content editable `onChange` event, call a function:

```
<div contententeditable="true" [change]="onNameChange(if.there.is.such.a.thing)">Type your name</div>

...

private name: string;

onNameChange(name) {
   this.name = name;
}
```

Any ideas on this? Thanks.

Comment: What problem are you having? Surely you can just add the `contenteditable` attribute?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the `input` event, like so:

```
<div contenteditable (input)="onNameChange($event.target.innerHTML)">
   Type your name
</div>
```

**[Here is a Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x2t4ju?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it be possible to include in your answer how the innerHtml is passed to the callback function?

Comment: @JhourladEstrella Sure, I've updated the answer and the example

Comment: How would you set an initial value (i.e. a previously saved value)? Also if the text has line breaks or tabs or whatnot you'd have to manually convert them to/from html tags. This really doesn't seem like a viable option for the most common use case of an expanding input, which is long runs of text.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a variable on element and on event input, get value from innerText

`<h2 contenteditable="true" #x (input)="item.title = x.innerText">{{item.title}}</h2>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).