# Angular Saving an Edited Content

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm writing a code where a user can change a paragraph on the screen and save it. Currently, the user can change the paragraph and the `save()` operation works. But when saved, the changed paragraph doesn't go through the network. The paragraph doesn't change it saves the unedited version as if I haven't written anything. What should I change to achieve that?

HTML:

```
  <div class="content fuse-white ml-24 mr-8 h-100-p" fusePerfectScrollbar>
            <div class="label-list">
                <p>
                    A Paragraph: 
    
                    <span contenteditable="true">
                        {{_stickerData?.StickerData}}
                    </span>
                </p>
              
            </div>
        </div>
```

TS:

```
save(){
    this.confirmDialogRef = this._dialog.open(FuseConfirmDialogComponent, {
        disableClose: false,
    });
    
    this.confirmDialogRef.componentInstance.confirmMessage =
    "The paragraph will be changed";

this.confirmDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
    if (result) {
        this._productionService
            .saveStickerData(this._stickerData)
            .subscribe((response: IStickerData) => {
                this._stickerData = response;
                this._messages.Show(            
                    "SUCCESS",
                    3
                );
            });
    }
});
}
```

Service TS:

```
saveStickerData(data: IStickerData): Observable<IStickerData> {
        return this._http.post("Production/SaveStickerData", data);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[EDITED]**
When you interpolate your variable in the template and use contenteditable - it doesn't update your variable. You should update it manually.

```
<span contenteditable [textContent]="_stickerData?.StickerData" (input)="onStickerDataChange($event.target.innerHTML)">
</span>
```

and in TS should be something like this:

```
onStickerDataUpdate(data) {
    this._stickerData.StickerData = data;
}
```

Useful Links: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53130362/angular-and-contenteditable), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35378087/how-to-use-ngmodel-on-divs-contenteditable-in-angular2)
**[OLD RECOMMENDATIONS]**

1. Are your sure that response has edited paragraph? If yes, Probably there is a problem with Change Detection. Import in component constructor ChangeDetectorRef and trigger markForCheck() method when getting data.
2. Nested subscriptions is a bad practice, try to refactor with switchMap()

This is a pseudocode to show the idea:

```
   class MyComponent {
      constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
        
       save(){
         this.confirmDialogRef = 
         this._dialog.open(FuseConfirmDialogComponent, {
            disableClose: false,});
         this.confirmDialogRef.componentInstance.confirmMessage =
    "The paragraph will be changed";

         this.confirmDialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(switchMap(result) => {
           if (result) {
             return this._productionService.saveStickerData(this._stickerData);
           } else {
             return EMPTY;
           }
        }).subscribe((response) => {
          this._stickerData = response;
          this._messages.Show(            
             "SUCCESS",
             3
          );
          this.cd.markForCheck();
        });
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you, I added ChangeDetectorRef to my code but, it still doesn't save the edited text.

Comment: @RocketMonkey. have you checked that you are sending exactly edited data to your production service? And the service responded with edited data too, not the previous one?

Comment: @RocketMonkey. It seems like contenteditable doesn't change your variable

Comment: I did. Yes the data I send and the service's response is correct. But what should I do in order to make contenteditable work?

Comment: Thank you, you are amazing. Now it saves the edited text. I can't see the new text when I refresh the page tho. Should I add something to the HTML?